# En MS SQL, ¿Cómo puedo ordenar los valores en las filas para que salgan de menor a mayor cuando los valores están en otra columna?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy organizando una tabla en una base de datos con todas las combinaciones de una lotería. En una tabla tengo todas las combinaciones, y en otra tabla tengo todos los números y las veces que han jugado en los últimos 20 sorteos. Con el siguiente query obtengo la unión de cada número que es parte de una combinación con su respectiva repetición. (La lotería consiste de 37 números, 1-37, sin que ningún número se repita en cada combinación.)

```
    SELECT ID,
    (convert(varchar, a.number1) + 
        '(' + convert(varchar, r.Repeated) + 'x)') as 'Number1', 

    (convert(varchar, a.number2) + 
        '(' + convert(varchar, e.Repeated) + 'x)') as 'Number2',        

    (convert(varchar, a.number3) + 
        '(' + convert(varchar, g.Repeated) + 'x)') as 'Number3',         

    (convert(varchar, a.number4) + 
        '(' + convert(varchar, y.Repeated) + 'x)') as 'Number4',    

    (convert(varchar, a.number5) + 
        '(' + convert(varchar, z.Repeated) + 'x)') as 'Number5'             

FROM [Fantasy5Combinations].[dbo].[Fantasy5FromExcel] a

  join dbo.NumbersRepetitions r on a.number1=r.NumberID
  join dbo.NumbersRepetitions e on a.number2=e.NumberID
  join dbo.NumbersRepetitions g on a.number3=g.NumberID
  join dbo.NumbersRepetitions y on a.number4=y.NumberID
  join dbo.NumbersRepetitions z on a.number5=z.NumberID

  order by a.number1, a.number2, a.number3, a.number4, a.Number5
```

Así, por ejemplo, el query produce los resultados de las combinaciones:

```
Number1 Number2 Number3 Number4 Number5
1(7x)   2(4x)   3(4x)   4(2x)   5(3x)
1(7x)   2(4x)   3(4x)   4(2x)   6(2x)
1(7x)   2(4x)   3(4x)   4(2x)   7(6x)
1(7x)   2(4x)   3(4x)   4(2x)   8(2x)
```

Se puede ver que el 1 ha salido 7 veces y el 5 lo ha hecho 3 veces, por lo que el orden que busco sería `4(2x) 5(3x) 2(4x) 3(4x) 1(7x)`, es decir `(2,3,4,4,7)` y así respectivamente con cada combinación. En pocas palabras, ¿cómo hago para intercambiar, cuando es el caso, el valor de una celda de la izquierda por el de la derecha y viceversa (o cuando es mayor por el menor)? La cantidad de combinaciones en la tabla es de `376,992`. El enlace que utilizo es este http://www.lotteryextreme.com/florida/fantasy5-hot_and_cold_numbers

Ejemplos cortos de las Tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fantasy5FromExcel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number5] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

```
INSERT INTO [Fantasy5Combinations].[dbo].[Fantasy5FromExcel]
           ([ID]
           ,[Number1]
           ,[Number2]
           ,[Number3]
           ,[Number4]
           ,[Number5])
VALUES
(1,2,3,4,5),
(1,2,3,4,6),
(1,2,3,4,7),
(1,2,3,4,8),
(1,2,3,4,9),
(1,2,3,4,10),
(1,2,3,4,11),
(1,2,3,4,12),
(1,2,3,4,13),
(1,2,3,4,14),
(1,2,3,4,15),
(1,2,3,4,16),
(1,8,19,24,34),
(1,8,19,24,35),
(1,8,19,24,36),
(1,8,19,25,26),
(1,8,19,25,27),
(1,8,19,25,28),
(2,13,17,20,26),
(2,13,17,20,27),
(2,13,17,20,28),
(2,13,17,20,29),
(2,13,17,20,30),
(3,8,14,28,29),
(3,8,14,28,30),
(3,8,14,28,31),
(3,8,14,28,32),
(3,8,14,28,33),
(30,33,34,35,36),
(31,32,33,34,35),
(31,32,33,34,36),
(31,32,33,35,36),
(31,32,34,35,36),
(31,33,34,35,36),
(32,33,34,35,36);

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NumbersRepetitions](
    [NumberID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Repeated] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Fantasy5Combinations].[dbo].[NumbersRepetitions]
           ([NumberID]
           ,[Repeated])
     VALUES
            (1,7),  (2,4),  (3,4),  (4,2),  (5,3),  
            (6,2),  (7,6),  (8,2),  (9,2),  (10,5), 
            (11,6), (12,2), (13,1), (14,2), (15,3), 
            (16,2), (17,0), (18,1), (19,3), (20,1), 
            (21,3), (22,2), (23,4), (24,2), (25,2), 
            (26,5), (27,5), (28,1), (29,3), (30,3), 
            (31,2), (32,3), (33,1), (34,2), (35,2), (36,2); 
GO
```

Comment: Incluye DDL please...

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto?
`SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: Quiero decir que para ayudarte deberías aportar las estructuras y datos mínimos donde probar lo que quieres. Por ejemplo: CREATE TABLE #t ([date] DATE,userid int,balance decimal(18,2));
insert into #t select '2018-09-01', 111, 1000 union select '2018-09-01', 222, 2000;

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: He agregado los ejemplos.